# Is there a way to delete a Bamboo agent using Atlassian Bamboo SDK or Bamboo REST API services?

Tags: java, bamboo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I know that it is possible to manually disable or delete an agent on the Bamboo agents page. I am writing a Bamboo plugin that should delete Bamboo agents when the build is completed. There does not seem to be a straight forward way to do that either using the Bamboo REST API or SDK library.

Comment: Good question, have you found a solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We (Atlassian Build Engineering) are doing something similar in our plugins that we recently open sourced at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/per-build-container

We create Docker based remote agents on demand, they build a job and then get removed.

Comment: I see that you are using ExecutableAgentsHelper to get list of agents matching requirement set. I am assuming that an object of ExecutableAgentsHelper is created when Reaper class is initialized. Can you please help me understand how to instantiate ExecutableAgentsHelper in other classes?                                                                                    
    `public class Reaper implements LifecycleAware {
    private final PluginScheduler pluginScheduler;
    private final ExecutableAgentsHelper executableAgentsHelper;
    private final AgentManager agentManager;`

Comment: ExecutableAgentsHelper should be auto injected into any of your components automatically. As is the case with the Reaper class. But it's slightly unrelated to the original question. You wanted to delete/disable an agent, that's what AgentRemovals class is mostly doing - https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/per-build-container/src/22d3925f857b841159aa85b040270d5e2b2eabc7/bamboo-isolated-docker-plugin/src/main/java/com/atlassian/buildeng/isolated/docker/AgentRemovals.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: what's to be noted and what we just got burned by recently is that ExecutableAgentsHelper is internal api, not public and can change without notice. and it indeed did between 6.1 and upcoming 6.2

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a modified version of what I found in https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/per-build-container shared by @mkleint. I added a query to get the list of agents based on job requirements.

```
import com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.ExecutableAgentsHelper;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.buildqueue.manager.AgentManager;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.AgentCommandSender;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgent;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.messages.StopAgentNicelyMessage;

class DeleteAgent{
    private AgentManager agentManager;
    private AgentCommandSender agentCommandSender;

    //Atlassian managed object and will be auto injected when this setter is found
    public void setAgentManager(AgentManager agentManager) {
    this.agentManager = agentManager;
  }

  //Atlassian managed object and will be auto injected when this setter is found
  public void setAgentCommandSender(AgentCommandSender agentCommandSender) {
      this.agentCommandSender = agentCommandSender;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RequirementSetImpl reqs = new RequirementSetImpl();
    reqs.addRequirement(new RequirementImpl("requirement-key","requirement-value");
    reqs.addRequirement(new RequirementImpl("requirement-key","requirement-value");
    Collection<BuildAgent> agentsToBeDeleted = executableAgentsHelper.getExecutableAgents(ExecutableAgentsHelper.ExecutorQuery.newQuery(reqs));
    Iterator<BuildAgent> agentsToBeDeletedIterator = agentsToBeDeleted.iterator();
    while(agentsToBeDeletedIterator.hasNext()) {
        this.deleteSingleAgentOnBambooServer(agentsToBeDeletedIterator.next());
    }
  }

  private void deleteSingleAgentOnBambooServer(BuildAgent agent) {
    if(agent!=null) {
        this.stopAgentRemotely(agent.getId());
        this.removeAgent(agent);
    }
  }

  public void stopAgentRemotely(BuildAgent buildAgent) {
     Long agentId = buildAgent.getId();
     String agentName = buildAgent.getName();
     buildAgent.setRequestedToBeStopped(true);
     agentCommandSender.send(new StopAgentNicelyMessage(), agentId);
 }

 public void stopAgentRemotely(long agentId) {
     BuildAgent ba = agentManager.getAgent(agentId);
     if (ba != null) {
         stopAgentRemotely(ba);
     }
 }

 public void removeAgent(BuildAgent agent) {
     if (agent != null) {
         removeAgent(agent.getId());
     }
 }

 public synchronized void removeAgent(long agentId) {
     BuildAgent ba = agentManager.getAgent(agentId);
     if (ba != null) {
         String agentName = ba.getName();
         try {
             agentManager.removeAgent(agentId);
         } catch (TimeoutException e) {
               System.out.println(String.format("timeout on removing agent %s (id: %s)", agentName, agentId), e);
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: what's to be noted and what we just got burned by recently is that ExecutableAgentsHelper is internal api, not public and can change without notice. and it indeed did between 6.1 and upcoming 6.2